# JS: Change innerHTML depending on CSS display state of an element

Tags: javascript

I am completely new to JS. I have a open-menu button which toggles a sidenav header. This works fine. Furhter I would like to change the hamburger icon to an X if the sidenav is opened (display: block) and again the hamburger icon if the sidenav is closed (display: none)

I have tried an if/else statement which checks the css display state of the sidenav but this does not work..

```
"use strict";

window.addEventListener("load", function() {

    let openMenu = document.getElementById("open-menu");

    openMenu.addEventListener("click", function () {

        let header = document.getElementById("sidenav");
        header.classList.toggle("toggle");
        openMenu.classList.toggle("z-index-9999");

    }, false);

    if (document.getElementById("sidenav").style.display == "none") {
        openMenu.innerHTML = "&#9776; Menü";
    } else {
        openMenu.innerHTML = "&times; Menü";
    }

}, false);

<button id="open-menu" type="button">&#9776; Menu</button>
<header id="sidenav">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            ...
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will fix everything but your if statement should be in the "click" handler and instead it's in the "load" handler. That means it will only run once on page load where I assume you'll want it to run every time someone clicks `openMenu`.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently checking the state of the element only once when the page is loaded. Try moving your condition inside the click event handler function like this:

```
 openMenu.addEventListener("click", function () {

    let header = document.getElementById("sidenav");
    header.classList.toggle("toggle");
    openMenu.classList.toggle("z-index-9999");

    openMenu.innerHTML = document.getElementById("sidenav")
        .style.display == "none" 
            ? "&#9776; Menü";
            : "&times; Menü";
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I get what you're attempting to do in this code. One thing that will help is the `getComputedStyle` function on an element, which tells you what the CSS has ultimately set as the final style for it. BUT, that won't work on its own because your code only runs when the page loads.

I would focus on the code that expands and retracts the sidebar. There may be a way to change that so that it turns on or off a single class that will then have multiple effects due to your CSS rules (including changing the content of an element)

```
#open-menu.menuOpen ~ #sidenav {
  /*When an element with ID open-menu has the menuOpen class, check for neighboring elements with id sidenav, and set their display property to block.*/
  display: block;
}

#open-menu.menuOpen:before {
  /* Display the &times character before the open-menu element, WHEN it has the menuOpen class */
  content: '&times;'
}

#open-menu:not(.menuOpen):before {
  /* Display the &#9776; character before the open-menu element, when it DOES NOT have the menuOpen class */
  content: '&#9776;'
}
```

Then to toggle:

```
// js
document.getElementById('open-menu').classlist.toggle('menuOpen');
```

This way, changing the open-menu button element to have or not have the menuOpen class will apply all the changes you want in a stateful way.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, but how would my complete JS Code look like with your line of code? I tried to remove my if/else statement and also some other things but I couldn't get to run it. Sorry, I'm completely new to JS.

Comment: @hause_13 I only have one line of JS in my example. You would have to put that line inside of a function that is called when the user clicks on the openMenu element. It seems like your example already has a click listener, so that would be the perfect place.